# Calling Cordova Plugin on Web App which is Displayed in InApp Browser

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

We want to use the in-app browser to load an external web site on our Cordova app. We also want to enable the external website to have a control to our Cordova capabilities / plugins, e.g., [SMS Plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/tree/master/docs).

Is it a feasible solution to call Cordova plugin code on the external website displayed in the in-app browser? If not, is there any workaround to let the external website call Cordova functionalities?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InAppBrowser was  designed to now allow access to Cordova plugins, so what you want to do is not possible.

Anyway, if what you want to do is to load an external website in a Cordova app, you don't really need InAppBrowser, there are multiple ways of loading an external website in the Cordova webview.

The easiest is to change the content tag src to point to your external website

```
<content src="http://www.externalwebsite.com" />
```

You will probably need to install the whitelist plugin (for Android) and allow navigation to that external website

```
<allow-navigation href="http://www.externalwebsite.com/*" />
```

But in case you don't have internet connection, Apple will notice and won't approve your app.

In that case you can keep the content src pointing to index.html and use the network information plugin to detect if there is internet connection or not, and then redirect to the external website with `window.location.href = "http://www.externalwebsite.com";` (you still need the whitelist plugin for this)

Comment: Thanks @jcesarmobile for your response.

Yes, I also put the `allow-navigation` rule on the config.xml file.


My next question would be, is it possible for the `externalwebsite.com` to access my cordova plugins capability on their code base? Let's say, in the `externalwebsite.com`, we have a button that switch on flash light on the mobile.

Comment: Yes, but you will need to serve the cordova.js file and it's different per platform, or inject the cordova.js content using java/Objective-C, and also the plugins .js files. It's not an easy task, but definitely possible.